# Can't resolve all parameters for LoginComponent: ([object Object], ?, ?) in ANGULAR

Tags: node.js, angular6

**i am building a imple login authentication using passport.js and i am getting this error this error has became i headache for me i am getting no error on my Gitcmd and node server but when i am trying to go to my browser i am getting this error**

**This is me user.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';


@Injectable()
export class UserService {

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }
  register(body:any){
    return this.http.post('http://127.0.0.1:3000/users/register',body,{
    observe:'body',
    headers:new HttpHeaders().append('Content-Type','application/json')
    })
  }
  login(body:any){
    return this.http.post('http://127.0.0.1:3000/users/login',body,{
      observe:'body',
      withCredentials:true,
      headers:new HttpHeaders().append('Content-Type','application/json')
      })
  }
}
```

**This is my login.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import {UserService} from '../user.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

    loginForm:FormGroup=new FormGroup({
      email:new FormControl(null,[Validators.email,Validators.required]),
      password:new FormControl(null,Validators.required)
    })
  constructor(private router:Router,private user,UserService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }
  //This is doing nothing just on Login Component when the 
  //User click Register button it takes it to Register Page

  moveToRegister(){
      this.router.navigate(['/register']);
  }
  //Now we have to Bind this function in our Html file
  login(){
    if(!this.loginForm.valid){
      console.log('Invalid');
      return;
    }
    // console.log(JSON.stringify(this.loginForm.value));
    this.user.login(JSON.stringify(this.loginForm.value))
    .subscribe(
      data=>{console.log(data);this.router.navigate(['/user']);},
      error=>console.error(error)
        )
  }
}
```

**this is mine app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './register/register.component';
import { UserhomeComponent } from './userhome/userhome.component';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import {UserService} from './user.service';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    RegisterComponent,
    UserhomeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [UserService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't have a comma here:

```
constructor(private router:Router,private user,UserService)
                                              ^
```

It should be:

```
constructor(private router: Router, private user: UserService)
```